# button not clicking not clicking dynamically - javascript

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to click a button dynamically using javascript to call a js function, when I launch the page, the javascript function is never called by the button to be clicked dynamically. here is my snippet

```
<button id="deSubmit" type="submit" >
    To be clicked automatically
</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("deSubmit").click();
</script>
```

Here is the js function I want to be called dynamically

```
$("#deSubmit").click(function () {
    $(function () {
        url_redirect({
            url: "${url}",
            method: "post"
        });
    });
........
```

Please what could be wrong

Comment: Have you added link to JQuery ?

Comment: sure I have add it

Comment: The event is called, but there's nothing to execute, since at this point the DOMReady has fired a long time ago, remove the function wrapper around the code you want to execute.

Comment: Call it in document.ready

Comment: @Teemu please post as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you want to click a button, you can write this function on load of script as well.

You need to enclose your code inside the document ready function to make sure your document loads before any JavaScript code is executed.

And for simplicity purpose, I have invoked click event using JQuery onlu.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#deSubmit").click(function() {
    /* url_redirect({
      url: "${url}",
      method: "post"
    });
    */
    alert('function called');
  });
  
  $('#deSubmit').click();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="deSubmit" type="submit">
  To be clicked automatically
  </button>
```

Comment: this solved the problem after all the attempts, maybe this is clicking with jQuery instead of plain javascript

Answer (score 2):

Call it in `document.ready`

```js
$("#deSubmit").click(function () {
  console.log("teste")
  /*$(function () {
    url_redirect({
      url: "${url}",
      method: "post"
    });
  });*/
}); 
  
$( document ).ready(function() {
     document.getElementById("deSubmit").click();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="deSubmit" type="submit" >To be clicked automatically</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Attach click event inside `document.ready`. Also `$(function () {` this wrapper is not required

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  document.getElementById("deSubmit").click();
})

$("#deSubmit").click(function() {
  console.log('test')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="deSubmit" type="submit">To be clicked automatically</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't complicate with jQuery and Javascript.

```js
  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

        const btn = document.getElementById("deSubmit");

        btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
          alert("here2")
        });

        btn.click();
    });
  </script>
```

Use above code this will work.. just put your code in place of the alert.